# How to install spatial4j into solr4

Tags: solr

Im exploring Solr4 and Polygons/linestrings.
There is some info on it here but not a howto/installation guide for a basic user like me.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4

As far as I understand, you need to install the spatial4j code into solr. (Im a hack at best).
https://github.com/spatial4j/spatial4j/tree/master/src/main/java

1. Does one know where I upload this code to, inside the solr4 installation? Keep in mind im using the /example/solr/collection1 directory.
2. "Due to a combination of things, JTS can't simply be referenced by a "" entry in solrconfig.xml; it needs to be in WEB-INF/lib in Solr's war file, basicall" Does anyone know what that means in terms of an installation instruction? Im after some guidance of what goes where. I use start.jar to start solr on my apache server.
3. After that I understand that I simply need to add a field type and field () to the schema and as far as that goes it should be installed.

Im trying to send it polygon and linestring queries to find all documents within a polygon or within a radius of a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr includes Spatial4j already; what it doesn't have is JTS, which is a java library (.jar file).  Download JTS from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/  (the .jar is within the .zip distro).  WEB-INF/lib is a java webapp reference within a WAR file.  example/webapps/solr.war is where that is.  A .war file is really a zip, and can either be in it's '.war' file form or be uncompressed in a plain directory layout.  So if you rename the '.war' to '.zip' in OSX it's trivial to double-click it in order to expand it.  But then rename the resulting directory to 'solr.war', and put aside the original war file to some other place as you won't be using it for now.  Take the JTS jar and put it in solr.war/WEB-INF/lib/.  When you start Solr, it'll have access to JTS.  If it doesn't have access due to whatever reason, you'll get a ClassNotFoundException pertaining to a JTS related Java class.

Comment: Thankyou. I did everything as suggested. Restarted server, solr works fine. If I make the changes to the schema.xml file as it says in the solr wiki (add field type, add field), I get "There are no SolrCores running" when I attempt to restart. Restoring the previous schema.xml file works again. Any ideas?

Comment: ok I did a bit more research, im using the solr ranking algorithm version from TA Gels and thats where I think the problem is, it might not have the SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType as per this link. http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/problem-using-spatialrecursiveprefixtreefieldtype-in-solr-dse

Comment: Just wanted to say that everything worked as per the above suggestions by David Smiley. A great easy to follow instruction for this newb.